# count consecutive vowels in words

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def openFile(fileName): 
  infile = open(fileName, "r")
  infile.readline() words = [] for data in infile: dataStrip = data.strip('\n') 
  words.append(dataStrip) return words

def findVowels(words): 
  splitWord = words.split() 
  for word in splitWord: 
    if word == "a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u": 
    return True 
  else: return False

def main(): 
  file = openFile("vowels.txt") 
  for word in file: 
    vowelCount = 0 
    if findVowels(word): 
      vowelCount += 1 
    else: vowelCount = vowelCount 
  print(f"{word} has {vowelCount} vowels in it") 
main()
```

So, this is what I have so far to find vowels in each word in the text file. It doesn't work, and I still need to be able to count how many consecutive vowels are in the words. If you can help, but make it to the level of simplicity I have done so far, that'd be great help. Lmk if you need more info.

Comment: `or "e"` is always true, and you're just returning on the first iteration of the for loop

Comment: This question needs more info I think. for example, what would `heeliumo` return? I'd expect 4 maybe, because the last vowel is just by itself there.

Comment: It'll be super helpful to provide sample input and output.

Comment: My apologies. Let me provide some examples: 
Inputs: words from a text file containing words with many consecutive vowels, single vowels, or none (i.e. dog, crpyt, food)
Output: only words with consecutive vowels, which will then be sorted and printed out in order from least amount to most amount.  food would return 2 consecutive vowels, queueing would return 5 consecutive vowels. I want it to also hold the vowels aeiou in a list. I want the list called vowels and it will do a for loop for each word in the text file.

Comment: Any more info? if so, lmk.

Comment: Just to make sure, if the word has any vowels in it, they will either all be consecutive, or it will be just a single one, right? For example the word "tone" cannot appear in your list.

Comment: you could add example words and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My version which search highest consecutive amount.

I use list for this

- if there is vowel then add +1 to last value on list (with curren consecutive vowels),
- if there is no vowel then append 0 at the end of list (to count next consecutive vowels)

And later I get max()

```
def count_vowels(word):

    all_results = [0]
    
    current = 0
    sequence = 1

    for char in word:
        if char in 'aeiou':
            all_results[-1] += 1  # update last item
        else:
            all_results.append(0) # add new last item
          
        print(char, all_results)
  
    return max(all_results)

def main():
    words = "aaabeehi9ooguuute queueing aeioua aaaTee BTW aaa aTa".split()
    for word in words:
        vowel_count = count_vowels(word)
        print(f"{word} has {vowel_count} vowels in it")

main()
```

Result: (which display also history of counting)

```
a [1]
a [2]
a [3]
b [3, 0]
e [3, 1]
e [3, 2]
h [3, 2, 0]
i [3, 2, 1]
9 [3, 2, 1, 0]
o [3, 2, 1, 1]
o [3, 2, 1, 2]
g [3, 2, 1, 2, 0]
u [3, 2, 1, 2, 1]
u [3, 2, 1, 2, 2]
u [3, 2, 1, 2, 3]
t [3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 0]
e [3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1]
aaabeehi9ooguuute has 3 vowels in it
q [0, 0]
u [0, 1]
e [0, 2]
u [0, 3]
e [0, 4]
i [0, 5]
n [0, 5, 0]
g [0, 5, 0, 0]
queueing has 5 vowels in it
a [1]
e [2]
i [3]
o [4]
u [5]
a [6]
aeioua has 6 vowels in it
a [1]
a [2]
a [3]
T [3, 0]
e [3, 1]
e [3, 2]
aaaTee has 3 vowels in it
B [0, 0]
T [0, 0, 0]
W [0, 0, 0, 0]
BTW has 0 vowels in it
a [1]
a [2]
a [3]
aaa has 3 vowels in it
a [1]
T [1, 0]
a [1, 1]
aTa has 1 vowels in it
```

---

**EDIT:**

Version which can count `highest consecutive vowels` and `highest consecutive non-vowels`. For `non-volwes` I use negative value and `min()`. Because sometime text may have only `vowels` or only `non-vowels` so I add extra `0` in `all_results`

```
def count_vowels(word):

    all_results = [0, 0]
    
    current = 0
    sequence = 1

    for char in word:
        if char in 'aeiou':
            if all_results[-1] < 0:
                all_results.append(0)
            all_results[-1] += 1  # update last item
        else:
            if all_results[-1] > 0:
                all_results.append(0) # add new last item
            all_results[-1] -= 1  # update last item
          
        print(char, all_results)
        
    return max(all_results), min(all_results)


def main():
    words = "aaabeehi9ooguuute queueing aeioua aaaTee BTW aaa aTa".split()
    for word in words:
        vowel_count = count_vowels(word)
        print(f"{word} | max vowels: {vowel_count[0]} | max non-vowels: {-vowel_count[1]}")

main()
```

Result:

```
a [0, 1]
a [0, 2]
a [0, 3]
b [0, 3, -1]
e [0, 3, -1, 1]
e [0, 3, -1, 2]
h [0, 3, -1, 2, -1]
i [0, 3, -1, 2, -1, 1]
9 [0, 3, -1, 2, -1, 1, -1]
o [0, 3, -1, 2, -1, 1, -1, 1]
o [0, 3, -1, 2, -1, 1, -1, 2]
g [0, 3, -1, 2, -1, 1, -1, 2, -1]
u [0, 3, -1, 2, -1, 1, -1, 2, -1, 1]
u [0, 3, -1, 2, -1, 1, -1, 2, -1, 2]
u [0, 3, -1, 2, -1, 1, -1, 2, -1, 3]
t [0, 3, -1, 2, -1, 1, -1, 2, -1, 3, -1]
e [0, 3, -1, 2, -1, 1, -1, 2, -1, 3, -1, 1]
aaabeehi9ooguuute | max vowels: 3 | max non-vowels: 1
q [0, -1]
u [0, -1, 1]
e [0, -1, 2]
u [0, -1, 3]
e [0, -1, 4]
i [0, -1, 5]
n [0, -1, 5, -1]
g [0, -1, 5, -2]
queueing | max vowels: 5 | max non-vowels: 2
a [0, 1]
e [0, 2]
i [0, 3]
o [0, 4]
u [0, 5]
a [0, 6]
aeioua | max vowels: 6 | max non-vowels: 0
a [0, 1]
a [0, 2]
a [0, 3]
T [0, 3, -1]
e [0, 3, -1, 1]
e [0, 3, -1, 2]
aaaTee | max vowels: 3 | max non-vowels: 1
B [0, -1]
T [0, -2]
W [0, -3]
BTW | max vowels: 0 | max non-vowels: 3
a [0, 1]
a [0, 2]
a [0, 3]
aaa | max vowels: 3 | max non-vowels: 0
a [0, 1]
T [0, 1, -1]
a [0, 1, -1, 1]
aTa | max vowels: 1 | max non-vowels: 1
```

---

**BTW:**

To count more types of chars - `vowels`, `consonants`, `digits`, `others` - I would use tuples `("vowels", 0)`, `("consonants", 0)` instead of `positive` and `negative` values.

---

**EDIT:**

Full code

I assume you have every word in separated line and you don't have header at the top of file.

```
def count_vowels(word):

    all_results = [0]
    
    current = 0
    sequence = 1

    for char in word:
        if char in 'aeiou':
            all_results[-1] += 1   # update last item
        else:
            all_results.append(0)  # add new last item
          
        #print(char, all_results)  # ie. `g [0, 5, 0, 0]`
  
    return max(all_results)

def read_words():
    fh = open("vowels.txt")   # `fh` means `file handler`

    text = fh.read()  # read all as one string

    fh.close()

    words = text.split("\n")   # split string into list of lines
    #words = text.splitlines()  # split string into list of lines
   
    #words = words[1:]  # skip first line with header

    #words = "aaabeehi9ooguuute queueing aeioua aaaTee BTW aaa aTa".split()

    return words

def main():

    # --- read ---
    
    words = read_words()

    # --- count ---

    words_with_counts = []
    
    for word in words:
        vowel_count = count_vowels(word)
        words_with_counts.append( (vowel_count, word) )
        
    # --- sort ---
    
    sorted_words_with_counts = sorted(words_with_counts) #, reverse=True)

    # --- display ---
    
    for vowel_count, word in sorted_words_with_counts:
        print(f"{word} has {vowel_count} vowels in it")

# --- main ---

main()
```

Comment: This is nice, and what I need. But, are you able to make it not show it counting them and just state: "*word* has a max amount of *vowel_count* consecutive vowels" Also, I had another function set up for reading a file that can be seen in my example code. If you could alter it for a txt file and have it print the words in order from least amount to most amount of consecutive vowels, that'd be great.

Comment: I apologize if I'm asking for much. You see, I am pursuing computer programming as a career, and am recently starting to learn from someone that isn't just me teaching myself. You've been a great help so far, thank you.

Comment: to remove some text you have to comment (or remove) some lines with `print()` - if you don't know which `print()` to comment then first comment first `print()` and run code to see if resolve problem. This should learn you something. As for file - `words = open(...).read().split("\n")` should give list with all words. As for wodrs in order - at start you have to create empty list and later append tuples `(vowel_count, word)` - and if you use `sorted( new_list )` then it will sort by `vowel_count` (and if two words will have the same `vowel_count` then it will sort them by `word`.

Comment: I added full code but I didn't test it with file.

Comment: if it's not too much to ask for, can you put that in code? I'm not sure what to do without visuals. I'm more of a visual learner, you see.

Comment: I don't know what you want because you have all in code.

Comment: sorry, you just confused me with the comments, as Idk if that's edited code you took away, or code you want me to add? If you clarify this that would be helpful

Comment: run last code without any changes. In comments you can find extra elements - like `print()` which shows step-by-step calcualations, or different methods for the same task like `.splitlines()` instead of `.split("\n")`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly. You can use two indexes and iterate over the word.

```
def count_vowels(word):
    vowel_count = 0

    current = 0;
    sequence = 1;
    while sequence < (len(word)):
        if (word[current] == 'a' or word[current] == 'e' or word[current] == 'i' or word[current] == 'o' or word[current] == 'u') \
                and (word[sequence] == 'a' or word[sequence] == 'e' or word[sequence] == 'i' or word[sequence] == 'o' or word[sequence] == 'u'):
            vowel_count += 1
        current += 1
        sequence += 1

    return vowel_count


def main():
    words = "aaabeehi9ooguuute queueing aeioua".split()
    for word in words:
        vowel_count = count_vowels(word)
        print(f"{word} has {vowel_count} vowels in it")


main()
```

Output:

```
aaabeehi9ooguuute has 6 vowels in it
queueing has 4 vowels in it
aeioua has 5 vowels in it
```

Comment: Well, the issue is your outputs are wrong.  Consecutive vowels are vowels that are next to each other with no non-vowels between them. Also, the count for your vowels looks to be wrong, as aeioua has 6 letters that are all vowels, and the output states it has 5 vowels in it.

Comment: @MafiaFelineBoss What should be the consecutive vowels to aeioua? I thought it should be --> ae, ei, io, ou, ua.

Comment: shorter `word[current] in ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u") and word[sequence] in ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")` or even `word[current] in "aeiou" and word[sequence] in "aeiou"`

Comment: the entire word aeioua is just consecutive vowels. It's a word with vowels without any non-vowel between them. Example: food has 2 consecutive vowels: "oo". nobody is has a single vowel, as there are no consecutive vowels.

Comment: @furas. I got it my mistake. But if we have aaaTee. It should count  5 consecutive vowels?

Comment: I didn't write about mistake but @MafiaFelineBoss wrote about it :) You asked about `aaaTee` wrong person.

Comment: I think you shouldn't use `vowel_count += 1` but add `current` and `sequence` to `set()` - and later check `len()` on this set. And this should give 5 for `aaaTee`

Comment: no no, the most amount of consecutive vowels in the word is 3, which is all 3 a's

Comment: the code should count the highest amount of consecutive vowels in the word

Comment: also @furas, if you don't mind, can you show an example by altering my code with yours?

Comment: @MafiaFelineBoss you didn't mention in question that it has to be `highest amount` - it only shows how important can be examples in question. So my code needs changes to find only `highest amount` - not sum of all.

Comment: yes, my mistake.